# unable to update textview immideately

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

i'm making a translation app in which i want to update a textview but it is not doing as i want.

```
final audioTranslate at[] = new audioTranslate[1];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_translate);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    spokentext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    translatedtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    at[0] = this;
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            if (b.getText().toString().equals("Start")) {
                //code
            }
            else{
                tv.setText("");  //these all 3 operations are happening after transfer method is finished.
                b.setText("Wait");  
                b.setEnabled(false);
                transfer();
            }
        }
    });
}

void transfer() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //socket connection
            //it is giving exception on below line too.
            //Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. 
            //java.lang.RuntimeException
            at[0].spokentext.setText(spoken);
        }
    };
t.start();
}
```

this is my layout file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_audio_translate"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="diverse.technologies.transcriber.audioTranslate">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:text="Start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Start" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not getting what is wrong with above exception i'm getting. i'm using the object of the view that is having the textview. please help.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is exactly?

Comment: you can't update `UI` from worker threads

Comment: I want to update texture tv at time when it's code is executed. And I am not able to update a textview named spokentext from the thread using the object if audiotranslate class itself. @Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 0):

Normal worker threads cannot modify UI elements like TextView. Run the code `at[0].spokentext.setText(spoken);` inside UI thread. In side your run method write

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {//Your code}}
```

However I do not recommend this type of native java coding. Use a Handler or AsyncTask

Comment: But I've done the same thing in the other activity of this application. It works just fine there. But here it does not.

Comment: Activity is different from Thread. Activity can modify UI directly.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your transfer method:

```
void transfer() {
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //socket connection
        //it is giving exception on below line too.
        //Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. 
        //java.lang.RuntimeException
        spokentext.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            at[0].spokentext.setText(spoken);
        }
    });

    }
};
t.start();
}
```

Comment: OK I'll try that. And how can I update text in the text box immediately when the code comes into execution

Comment: this should post immediately, it is not a postdelayed

Comment: So u mean that I should use post method on my textview "tv" too. To update it immediately.

Comment: from your code, tv should be set to empty immediately after clicking button if button text doesn't equal "start"

Comment: It does not work like that. It sets to empty after the transfer method finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Pavneet_Singh said, you cannot update your UI from another thread. Instead of calling `transfer()`, you probably want to do it like this.

```
public class YourActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = (Button) v;
                if (b.getText().toString().equals("Start")) {
                    //code
                } else {
                    tv.setText("");  //these all 3 operations are happening after transfer method is finished.
                    b.setText("Wait");  
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                    new RetrieveSpokenTextTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class RetrieveSpokenTextTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String spoken = "the value you would like to assign to the TextView";
            return spoken;
        }

        @Override
        public void postExecute(String text) {
            // the `text` variable has now the string you returned in `doInBackground`
            spokentext.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @abhishek-panjabi how are you able to execute that produces an exception if it does not even call `t.start()` inside `transfer()`. i'm sorry, i do not have enough reputation so i cannot comment on your post directly.

Comment: It certainly does call t.start man. I forgot to enter that line in my question.

Comment: Have you tried using an AsyncTask? Maybe that's what you would like to use. You can perform long running tasks inside the `doInBackground` method and then perform the changes in the user interface in the `postExecute` method.

Comment: @abhishek-panjabi i've edited my answer just in case you'd like to check out the usage of AsyncTask in your code.